# Does the lifetime of an array object end when its' element storage is reused?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++17, language-lawyer, lifetime

In the subsequent quotes, I'm referring to the ISO standard draft N4713.

§ 6.6.3, paragraph 1 says:

> ...The lifetime of an object o of type T ends when:
>   ...
>   — the storage which the object occupies is released, or is reused
>   by an object that is not nested within o (6.6.2).

Please answer the questions in the code comments:

```
#include <new>

int main() {
    int x[2] = {0, 1};
    char* p = new (x + 1) char{0}; // Has x ended its' lifetime?
    int z = x[0];                  // Is this UB?
}
```

If I used `unsigned char` as array element type, the array object `x` would have provided storage for the `*p`, according to § 6.6.2, paragraph 3:

> If a complete object is created (8.5.2.4) in storage associated with
>   another object e of type “array of N unsigned char” or of type “array
>   of N std::byte” (21.2.1), that array provides storage for the created
>   object if:
>   — the lifetime of e has begun and not ended, and
>   — the
>   storage for the new object fits entirely within e, and
>   — there is no
>   smaller array object that satisfies these constraints.

Please, validate my statements in the code comments:

```
#include <new>

int main() {
    unsigned char x[2] = {0, 1};
    char* p = new (x + 1) char{0}; // Only x[1] have ended its' lifetime.
    int z = x[0];                  // This is OK.
}
```

Although I do not understand the last rule in the previous quote, please give an example?

> there is no smaller array object that satisfies these constraints.

Comment: § 6.6.2, paragraph 3 refers to an array of `unsigned char` or an array of `std::byte`. Your example has neither (your array if of `int`), so that section does not apply.

Comment: There seems to be a more fundamental flaw with your setup. § 6.6.3, paragraph 1 stipulates *"that is not nested within"*, while § 6.6.2, paragraph 3 requires *"the storage for the new object fits entirely within".* That is, § 6.6.3, paragraph 1 applies when one object is not nested within another, while § 6.6.2, paragraph 3 applies only if one *is* nested within the other. The two paragraphs cannot both apply to your scenario.

Comment: _"Although I do not understand the last rule in the previous quote, please give an example?"_ There is an example after the normative text https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.object#3.example-1

Comment: The lifetime of array ends, but `int z = x[0];` seems not to be UB, because array-to-pointer conversion and pointer arithmetic don't require an array or its elements to be within their lifetime. And the lifetime of `x[0]` hasn't ended, because its storage wasn't reused.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer
> pointer arithmetic don't require an array or its elements to be within their lifetime
Can you point out the rule in the standard, please?
>And the lifetime of x[0] hasn't ended, because its storage wasn't reused
You imply that when an object ends its' lifetime subobjects continue to live... Is there a rule in the standard that regulates this situation?

Comment: There is no rule explicitly saying that «pointer arithmetic don't require an array or its elements to be within their lifetime», the rule about pointer arithmetic just doesn't depend on lifetime.

Comment: _"You imply that when an object ends its' lifetime subobjects continue to live... Is there a rule in the standard that regulates this situation?"_ You've cited the rule when an object's lifetime ends: when it is destroyed or when its storage is reused. As you can see, there is no rule saying "when the lifetime of its containing object ends".

Answer (score 0):

According to the following reading of the standard, the array lifetime is not ended by the placement new expression:

[basic.life]/1.5:

> The lifetime of an object o of type T ends when:
>
> - [...]
> - the storage which the object occupies is released, or is reused by an object that is not nested within o ([intro.object]).

According to this rule, if the new object created within the array is not nested within the array, the array life time end. Otherwise it is not ended.

[intro.object]/2

> If an object is created in storage associated with a member subobject or array element e (which may or may not be within its lifetime), the created object is a subobject of e's containing object if:
>
> - the lifetime of e's containing object has begun and not ended, and
> - the storage for the new object exactly overlays the storage location associated with e, and
> - the new object is of the same type as e (ignoring cv-qualification).

The two last bullets are not full-filled, so obviously, the new char object is not a suboject of the array.

Then [intro.object]/3:

> If a complete object is created ([expr.new]) in storage associated with another object e of type “array of N unsigned char” or of type “array of N std​::​byte” ([cstddef.syn]), that array provides storage for the created object if:
>
> - the lifetime of e has begun and not ended, and
> - the storage for the new object fits entirely within e, and
> - there is no smaller array object that satisfies these constraints.

So the array of unsigned char provides storage for the new char object.

[intro.object]/4:

> An object a is nested within another object b if:
>
> - a is a subobject of b, or
> - b provides storage for a, or
> - there exists an object c where a is nested within c, and c is nested within b.

As we mentioned above, the first bullet is not full-filled. The second one is full-filled. So according to [basic.life]/1.5, the lifetime of the array is not ended because the new char object is nested within the array:

```
int main() {
    unsigned char x[2] = {0, 1};
    char* p = new (x + 1) char{0}; // x provides storage for the char object
    int z = x[0];                  // OK The first element is within its lifetime.
}
```

If it were not the case, probably that most of the low-level code would not be standard compliant!

Comment: are you sure that the lifetime is not ended? it is not really 100% clear what "provides storage" means in the definition of the nested object. For example, the standard clearly says that only std::byte or unsigned chart provides storage: http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.memobj#intro.object-3. But your answer assumes that it just covers any storage.